# EventHandler type with no event args

Tags: c#, events, signals

When we want to pass data to an event subscriber, we use EventArgs (or CustomEventArgs) for this.

.Net provides a build in type EventHandler that uses as a parameter an instance of EventArgs class that is build in as well.

What about cases, when I need to notify a subscriber that some action is over, for example search is over? I don't want to even use EventArgs, that won't contain anything.

Is there a build in type for signaling another class, without the need to use empty EventArgs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have several options:

1. Use a normal event with an `EventHandler` and the basic `EventArg` class – sure the event is empty, but does this do any harm?
2. Make your own delegate and use this with `event MyDelegateWithoutParams MyEvent;`
3. Use the Observer Pattern with `IObservable` instead.
4. Let clients pass an `Action` to you and call this action.

I hope one of these options is to your liking. I use 1 and 4 for this kind of situation (4 mostly, if there will be only one "listener").

PS: I guess 2 won't conform to the [.NET framework guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-publish-events-that-conform-to-net-framework-guidelines), so maybe that one is not the best idea ;)

Answer (score 16):

I really would advise you to use the standard EventHandler pattern here and just pass `EventArgs.Empty`. However, you *can* use `Action` as an event type if you really want – it is just unusual.

Answer (score 8):

if you use plain `delegates` surely you can do what you want but if you use `events` I think the best is to stick on the standard and always have `object` sender and `EventArgs` e.

if you really do not know what to pass on firing those events from your own code, just pass `EventArgs.Empty` as second parameter.

Answer (score 8):

Use Actions (below answer copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1689341/1288473):

Declaring:

```
public event Action EventWithoutParams; 
public event Action<int> EventWithIntParam;
```

Calling:

```
EventWithoutParams?.Invoke(); 
EventWithIntParam?.Invoke(123);
```

Comment: This is the most direct answer to the OP's question