# Is EvenHandler without EventArgs OK?

Tags: c#, event-handling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [EventHandler type with no event args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7455357/eventhandler-type-with-no-event-args)

I am creating event handlers and the corresponding event args (`:EventArgs`) thorough my project. But I am wondering if I need this `EventArgs` object. As I often have in this `EventArgs` on property, corresponding to this specific `EventHandler`.

**Why should I need an EventArgs object where I could directly used the value?**

I understand the value of using a specific object container like this sometimes. But most of the time I just need to pass one or two objects. **Example:** Why `PropertyChangedEventHandler` bothers itself using an EventArgs where a String would be enough? Does that not bring overhead?

Comment: Sorry, you are right on both points.
I flagged this as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's a .NET convention to make event handlers uniform by accepting two parameters: the source of the event (`sender`) and the event args wrapped in a generic `EventArgs` object.

> Why PropertyChangedEventHandler bothers itself using an EventArgs
>   where a String would be enough? Does that not bring overhead?

No, because you pass a reference anyway, so no data actually gets moved around.

Comment: It is a guideline yes.
Thanks, I feel lighter then

Answer (score 0):

Generally, my suggestion would be to use the [Observer pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternObserver.aspx).

Also: [EventHandler type with no event args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7455357/eventhandler-type-with-no-event-args)