# What is the rationale for the rule "Event Handlers should have the correct signature"

Tags: c#, sonarqube

Consider the rule [RSPEC-3906](https://rules.sonarsource.com/csharp/RSPEC-3906):

> Delegate event handlers (i.e. delegates used as a type of an event) should have a very specific signature:
>
> - Return type void.
> - First argument of type System.Object and named 'sender'.
> - Second argument of type System.EventArgs (or any derived type) and is named 'e'.

The alternative just uses `Action` like described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1689341/2303202). I have some seen some amount of events done like this in a codebase and it seems to work with no issues. Moreover, it feels advantageous to have some static type of event compared to one signature for all cases.

Question: is there a scenario when not following this rule can cause any issues?

Comment: Yes... when you need a sender. Next question

Comment: The names of the parameters don't matter (e.g.: `sender` could be called `bob`). What matters is the number of parameters, their types and their order as that controls what information gets pushed onto the stack when they are invoked by the event source. If you somehow trick the compiler into adding a `void(object sender, SomethingElse other)` handler to an event that should only be calling a `void(object sender)` handler then you will likely crash the program inside your tricky handler when it tries to access the stack variables inappropriately.